# bufferedWriter.flush() example

Tags: android, flush, bufferedwriter

I'm looking to clear a text file in an android application and then rewrite to it the new ArrayList. My code in question is

```
try{
                    bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("Account.txt", MODE_APPEND)));
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    for( int j = 0; j < ((ArrayHandler)getApplicationContext()).info.size(); j++)
                    {
                        if( text.equalsIgnoreCase(((ArrayHandler)getApplicationContext()).info.get(j).getAccountName()))
                        {
                            ((ArrayHandler)getApplicationContext()).info.remove(j);

                            for( int k = 0; k < ((ArrayHandler)getApplicationContext()).info.size(); k++)
                            {
                                String account = ((ArrayHandler)getApplicationContext()).info.get(k).getAccountName();
                                String name = ((ArrayHandler)getApplicationContext()).info.get(k).getUserName();
                                String pass = ((ArrayHandler)getApplicationContext()).info.get(k).getPassword();

                                writeFileToStorage(account, name, pass);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception err)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cannot flush file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

I always get the catch clause when this code is ran. The file gets read in correctly, but if the user deletes something from the ArrayList then the file needs to remove the items that correspond to the ArrayList. My question is, how does one write this properly?

**Edit**
The code in question works. However there are a few changes that need to be done.
this:

```
bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("Account.txt", MODE_APPEND)));
```

needs to be changed to

```
bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("Account.txt", MODE_PRIVATE)));
```

and this:

```
bufferedWriter.close();
```

needs to be added after

```
bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("Account.txt", MODE_PRIVATE)));
bufferedWriter.flush();
```

to look like this:

```
bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("Account.txt", MODE_PRIVATE)));
bufferedWriter.flush();
bufferedWriter.close();
```

Thanks. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Try outputting the exceptions error message to the log, and post it's information here.  It would make it much easier to diagnose the issue.

Comment: When you remove the element from the array, is there a reason you switched from using j to i as the variable?

Comment: I noticed that as soon as I ran it. Thanks. I just need to make sure the file gets flushed properly now.